# Audio Playback Error - XCODE 7 (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, audio, swift2, xcode7, avaudioplayer

I am new to XCODE and Swift 2.0 programming.  When I try to test the added audio my app I gives me the error below.

-See screenshot for error-

[Screenshot of Xcode 7 Simulator error when trying to play Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8MPs.png)

Can someone please assist me in fixing this so that I can test my app in the simulator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with SoundFlower.  Removed SoundFlower and sound started to work again.